# How do you register an event listener to the appear/disappear events of the virtual keyboard on Blackberry Playbook using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

Not why no one has been complaining about this but I'm have a lot of problems with the Blackberry Playbook Virtual Keyboard on the Simulator.

I have an richedit component in the middle of the screen and as soon as the virtual keyboard appears to enter text, it completely hides the text input. I'd like to move the text input up when the keyboard appears/disappears. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to muck around with the focus_in and focus_out events on the richedit. I've tried, and it's not very reliable.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We expect the next release of the SDK (long overdue at this point but, I think, imminent) to provide much more complete support for the virtual keyboard.  Until that occurs, I think it's a waste of time to attempt to do anything special with it.

I also think there's a chance it will automagically move your whole stage up when it would cover up a text input, so maybe you won't have to do anything about it anyway.

**Edit**: Actually I published code in January describing an [undocumented way](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Is-there-is-a-way-to-capture-event-when-virtual-on-screen/m-p/738023/highlight/true#M6142) to support this, using some rudimentary PPS support.  It also shows how you can  programmatically control the keyboard opening and closing.  I don't recommend it yet for real code...

Comment: Aw man, I've already retrofitted the app to move the view up to text input.